# Search for questions older than an hour?

Tags: feature-request, search, fastest-gun

The [search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) has some ability to search by date, but is there any finer grained ability to search for questions less than a day old?

Typically, I browse through a tag looking for interesting questions, but I would like to exclude questions less than an hour old since I feel like I'm in a race to answer those, especially in the more popular tags.

More than once have I written an answer only to have another user post basically the same answer a few minutes before me.

If there's no facility to search by an "older than", is there another method to exclude very young questions?

How to others deal with this problem?  If I'm going to spend the time to write an answer, it would be nice to know that somebody probably isn't going to beat me to the punch.

Comment: I'd expect the search engine to have removed the times from the index and only support searching by date.

Comment: I don't think you can do this inside the search itself, but you could order by newest and then just skip however many pages you need to to get to the sufficiently old posts.

Comment: I use a query like this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+answers:0+score:1+created:2015-06-09+intags:mine to find posts in my tags, with a positive score and no answers

Comment: I'd love to have a search option where I can put in a minimum relative age of the question appearing to the general public (daysold: 1 or minutesold: 15 or something).

Comment: Well I guess you could make a script that would hide the young questions so only the older ones would appear.

Comment: "More than once have I written an answer only to have another user post basically the same answer a few minutes before me."  Don't you just hate that? :p

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know such a query, but as I also don't want to see the newest in my tag I instantly select the second page of the newest questions, that usually gives a better result.

Like this (for java): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: I think this is probably the best work-around until a feature is added to search by age less than a day.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but I've found that you can search using created time by extending the date search to include a timestamp. Adding the timestamp allows you to filter to posts created after a certain time (as opposed to older than an hour as you asked).

For instance you can search [unanswered questions, in your tags that were created after 2pm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine%20answers%3A0%20created%3A2015-06-10T13%3A00%3A00) (note search times are in UTC from what I can gather hence 1 hour difference in my location).

> intags:mine answers:0 created:2015-06-10T13:00:00

This doesn't seem to work with a time range however, so [filtering to an half hour period](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine%20answers%3A0%20created%3A2015-06-10T13%3A25%3A00..2015-06-10T13%3A20%3A00):

> intags:mine answers:0 created:2015-06-10T13:00:00..2015-06-10T13:30:00

Produces the same as searching by the first value in the range.

There might be a way, I'm still currently testing.

Answer (score 3):

```
created:1d
```

- The minimum range is a day.
- Select the `newest` tab.

Answer (score -1):

I usually go to the Newest tab, then randomly hit a few pages in.  The farther out I go, the more I like to think that I've helped someone who's given up hope getting an answer just because it's no longer recent.

I find this process satisfying, and hope the OP does too.  At least from my experience, I've noticed that if I post a question late in the night (or some random low traffic time) and there are less users online in that specific time period, questions seem to accumulate faster than their respective answers (on average) which makes the question get swamped into next pages (which decrease chances of it ever getting answered (or even viewed)).

I wish SO could incorporate something like this into their model.  The OP is onto something here.